# What is a mixed mode assembly?

Tags: sqlite, .net-4.0, assemblies, system.data.sqlite

I am looking at the System.Data.SQLite download [page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), and it lists mixed mode assembly for .NET 4 and a regular (I assume).  My project that is going to use this library is all .NET 4 which will be compiled to x86.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is a mixed-mode assembly?  Google returns a confusing array of answers, none of which make a lot of sense.  One answer states that it's all about mixing native and managed code, while others claim its for mixing .Net versions.
2. Which download should I get for my situation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx

1) Allways check msdn first. Mixed mode means that the assembly can run managed and unmanaged code.

2) Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)

http://system.data.sqlite.org/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.74.0.exe

You kinda answered that question yourself "My project that is going to use this library is all .NET 4 which will be compiled to x86."

Comment: So effectively mixed mode assemblies are always written in c++?

Comment: And you are saying that I should use the mixed-mode assembly.  I am still unclear as to why.

Comment: Because there are only mixed-mode assemblys. This is because the sqlite 'functionality' is written in C (COM) and you access it via a wrapper for .NET. So the assembly contains C and C# Code --> mixed mode assembly.

Comment: Ahh now I got what u mean....

The difference is, that a mixed-mode assembly is 1 .dll file that contains the functinality and the .NET wrapper.

If you don't use mixed-mode assembly you will have a SQLite.dll and a second DLL (SQlite.Interop.dll or however they call it) for the wrapper, so you dont have mixed codes within 1 dll

Comment: Neither SQLite3.dll, nor SQLite.Interop.dll have managed code - see [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q10)
. When not using the "System.Data.SQLite.dll" mixed mode assembly, then you must use another "System.Data.SQLite.dll" with a "SQLite.Interop.dll" file, which contain the managed code and native code, respectively - see [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q15)
.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to produce a mixed-mode assembly from pure IL. The final part of creating an assembly using reflection involves a call to [AssemblyBuilder.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145516.aspx). If you just pass PortableExecutableKinds.Required32Bit for the portableExecutableKind argument then you will create a mixed-mode assembly. You can avoid the problems this causes by also passing PortableExecutableKinds.ILOnly. i.e.

```cs
    assembly_bldr.Save(exe_name, PortableExecutableKinds.Required32Bit | PortableExecutableKinds.ILOnly, ImageFileMachine.I386 );
```

Needless to say, this information was hard won...

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the official [FAQ](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q14)

> (14) What is a mixed-mode assembly?
>
> A mixed-mode assembly is a dynamic link library that contains both
>   managed code and native code for a particular processor architecture.
>   Since it contains native code it can only be loaded into a process
>   that matches the processor architecture it was compiled for. Also see
>   this StackOverflow question.

It even references this question!

Answer (score 1):

For SQLite, the bundle contains a mixed-mode assembly for `System.Data.SQLite`; however, the default package contains two separate assemblies, one completely native, and the other an interop assembly which is completely managed.

There's actually a [FAQ](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q14) for this on the SQLite site.

> #### (15) What is a "bundle" package (i.e. from the download page)?
>
> The "bundle" packages listed on the download page contains the
>   System.Data.SQLite mixed-mode assembly in a file named
>   "System.Data.SQLite.dll" (see question #14) instead of separate
>   "System.Data.SQLite.dll" and "SQLite.Interop.dll" files to contain the
>   managed code and native code, respectively.

And the previous FAQ:

> #### (14) What is a mixed-mode assembly?
>
> A mixed-mode assembly is a dynamic link library that contains both
>   managed code and native code for a particular processor architecture.
>   Since it contains native code it can only be loaded into a process
>   that matches the processor architecture it was compiled for. Also see
>   this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266936).

### Why are there two options?

[Based on my research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/pure-and-verifiable-code-cpp-cli?view=vs-2019), the non-bundled form is available so that you can use `P/Invoke` in managed code (e.g. C#) to call into unmanaged code, rather than using [IJW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/interoperability-overview). IJW is [magically better](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2234/using-ijw-in-managed-c), and the mechanism to compile a C++ program into separate managed and unmanaged DLLs like this (so that `P/Invoke` even applies) is [deprecated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/compiler-switch-deprecationremoval-changes-in-visual-studio-14/) as of VS 2015, so newer versions of SQLite might drop the non-bundled package.

You should double-check my research, as I don't have direct evidence of anything in the preceding paragraph. Here's my research:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/mixed-native-and-managed-assemblies?view=vs-2019
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/interoperability-overview
- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8977675-do-not-remove-clr-pure-and-clr-safe-from-c-cli

Comment: another reason of two options I think is for AnyCpu project.